# Make alias from subdomains

Tags: php, .htaccess, alias, web-hosting, subdomain

I'd like to make some subdomains as: blog.mywebsite.eu, eshop.mywebsite.eu, www.mywebsite.eu etc... And I'd like them act like it's always the same. So I'd like to redirect them always into www dir.

I'd like just add some condition into my CMS that if url is blog.... then... etc.

I'm using PHP and I have own server. And also I'd like to know if there is a way how to do that on some webhosting. Can I do it through .htaccess? I'd like not to redirect but act like alias.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your rule needs to look something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.eu$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://blog.mywebsite.eu/$1 [R=301,L]
```

the `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable is *only* the hostname, and no path information is part of it (e.g. `/blog`). The `RewriteRule` takes at least 2 parameters:

```
RewriteRule <pattern to match against the URI> <if matched, rewrite/redirect to this URL> <flags>
```